Calculate shipping cost by weight using an array of tiered prices
I need to find the cost to ship a box, based on an array of weight rules, similar to this:
$rules = [
    '1'     => '1.2',
    '5-10'  => '6.25',
    '10-15' => '9.2',
    '15-20' => '10.9',
];

The goal is to optimize the result so that the fewest number of rules are used with the lowest possble cost.
For a box that weighs 47 lbs, these sets of rules would technically reach the weight:

(1)x47
(5-10)x5
(10-15)x3,(1)x2
(15-20)x3
(15-20)x2,(10-15)x1
(15-20)x2,(5-10)x1
etc.

The best/desired pricing calculation would be (15-20) $10.90 + (15-20) $10.90 + (5-10) $6.25 = $28.05 USD to ship.  This is the sum of the cheapest combination of prices.
At first, for simplicity, I created an intermediate array (of the upper limits of each ranges rule) like this (1 doesn't have an upper/lower limit, but that's easy to exclude):
$tiers = [
    20,
    15,
    10,
    1,
];

And then I tried to distribute the initial weight to that array in a way similar to a factorization process. So at first I totally ignored the lower limits, and took a weight, ie. 37.75 lbs. Then, using the following code, I produced the "factorization" array of each weight tier:
print_r( distribute( 37.75 );

function distribute( $weight = 0 ) {
    $tiers = [1, 10, 15, 20];

    rsort( $tiers );

    foreach ( $tiers as $tier ) {
        $counters[$tier] = 0;
    }

    foreach ( $tiers as $tier ) {
        $quotient  = $weight / $tier;
        $floored   = floor( $quotient );
        $remaining = $weight - $floored * $tier;

        if ( $quotient >= 1 && $remaining > 1 ) {
            $counters[$tier] = $floored;
            $weight          = $remaining;
        } else if ( $tier == 1 ) {
            $counters[$tier] = ( $floored + 1 );
            $weight          = $weight - ( $floored + 1 ) * $tier;
        }
    }

    return $counters;
}

Which conveniently produced an output like this:
    Array (
        [20] => 1
        [15] => 1
        [10] => 0
        [1] => 3
    )

Then, I tried the same code with weight 38, and realized my first mistake... There is some problem with an edge case that I can't figure out yet, that for 38 still adds a +1 to the 1-tier rule.
Then, I tried 47.75 lbs, and found the second mistake... As I said, for simplicity, I used the upper limits, which messes with the "factorization" of a weight. So, for 47.75 lbs, the above code produced an output like this:
    Array (
        [20] => 2
        [15] => 0
        [10] => 0
        [1] => 8
    )    

which is totally wrong, as consuming 1-tier 8 times is not the most economical path.
All in all, unfortunately, my approach is flawed in many ways. Can someone help me please figure out the correct code to deal with this problem?

Your 'tiers' array looks wrong, you have 1, 10, 15 & 20 - as most of these values are the upper bound (10, 15, 20) you first one I would have thought should be 5 and not 1.

I find the inconsistent structure of your weight ranges to be fiddly to work with, BUT I understand exactly why it needs to be that way -- so that individual pounds are summed correctly.
I've created a script to attempt to find the cheapest qualifying tier, log the tier data, substract the max of the range from the input weight, then repeat.  This appears to work on all tests that I've created.
Code: (Demo)
function costFromWeight($weight, array $newRules): array {
    $parsed = [];
    foreach ($newRules as $range => $cost) {
        if (sscanf($range, '%d-%d', $min, $max) === 1) {
            $default = [$min, $min, (float) $cost];
        } else {
            $parsed[]  = [$min, $max, (float) $cost];
        }
    }
    
    $result = ['cost' => 0];
    while ($weight > 0) {
        foreach ($parsed as $i => [$min, $max, $cost]) {
            if ($weight <= $max) {
                if (!$i && $weight <= $min) {  // weight is lower than lowest range, use defaults
                    [$min, $max, $cost] = $default;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        $result[$max] = ($result[$max] ?? 0) + 1;
        $result['cost'] += $cost;
        $weight -= $max;
    }
    return $result;
}

$rules = [
    '1'   => '1.2',
    '5-10'  => '6.25',
    '10-15' => '9.2',
    '15-20' => '10.9',
];

foreach ([49, 47.75, 38, 35, 23, 15, 14, 10.5, 4] as $weight) {
    echo "$weight :: ";
    print_r(costFromWeight($weight, $rules));
    echo "\n---\n";
}

Output:
49 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 28.05
    [20] => 2
    [10] => 1
)

---
47.75 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 28.05
    [20] => 2
    [10] => 1
)

---
38 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 21.8
    [20] => 2
)

---
35 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 20.1
    [20] => 1
    [15] => 1
)

---
23 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 14.5
    [20] => 1
    [1] => 3
)

---
15 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 9.2
    [15] => 1
)

---
14 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 9.2
    [15] => 1
)

---
10.5 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 9.2
    [15] => 1
)

---
4 :: Array
(
    [cost] => 4.8
    [1] => 4
)

---


Mickmackusa  that's almost what I also need, except for that 'cost' key is not important to my case, but instead I'd like to pass the $newRules array by reference, so that the function directly adds to it. Could you please help me with that?

Let me clarify what I mean by "the function should directly add to the rules array". So the rules array doesn't have the cost of each range as its values, but "times" adder. So supposing that it already contains some ranges (keys) and the frequency of that range, I'd like the function to add the frequency calculated for each of the ranges to the existing ones.

Wait a sec, you almost tricked me.  You are not the asker of this question.  If you have a new question which is related to but not resolved by this page, then... please ask a new question, offer a reference link to this page, and isolate/explain the part that you cannot resolve.  I am available to answer questions today because it is a public holiday.  Be sure to include a sufficiently difficult [mcve].

Unfortunately I can't right now, as I'm not able to ask questions for some more time... But I found it myself. Would you care to confirm my changes though? It seems to work fine, but a confirmation would be appreciated. If so, I can send you a minimal reproducible example.

Mickmackusa here it is https://onlinephp.io/c/f03c4

@Faye Do you need all this convolution?  Do you need the non-ranged first element?  I fear there is too much business logic that I don't know.  Does this much simpler script suit all of your needs? https://3v4l.org/dYoTS

mickmackusa the $weight_distribution initial array will have its keys exactly as in my MRE; only its values will differ. That is, there will be a faux range with a key equal to 1, and then the legit ranges with min-max limits.

I can't think of any meaningful refinements to make. https://3v4l.org/dBsO8  ++ is just a simpler way of writing += 1.
